# Make an AJAX queue to resolve request later

Tags: jquery, ajax, concurrency, deferred

I'm looking at `Deferred` object in `jQuery`. 
What I'm thinking about is how to make a queue of request that are called before a particular request , but should be resolved only after this last one.

I explain :

I am inserting **tags** . Every time I insert a tag, I should insert it into a **database** through an `AJAX` request. To make this `AJAX` request I need an `id` that is generated by another `AJAX` request that I will call later.

I think it can be resolved through `.promise()` but I didn't understand how is it working.

Here is an example in *pseudo-code* of what I am trying to achieve :

```
ajaxReq(id) //is called every time I insert a tag
generateId() //this generate the id a need

when generateId is called -> ajaxReq is resolved (even if i "called" it before)
```

Comment: looks like your logic is failing somewhere. Why not then call generateId() before ajaxReq(id)? Why not using only one request? Could you provide a specific example?

Comment: 'cause I need to avoid useless tables in my Database . If the users does not insert tag or does any of the action i need to fill tables related to the generated id, it's useless to create one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does appear that your information flow is incorrect.  You simply *cannot* make the "first" AJAX request until the second one has been completed and assigned the ID.

In essence, you just need a local list of tags that are waiting to be submitted:

```
var tags = [];
```

and a way to add tags to the list:

```
// Add a new tag to the queue
function makeTag() {
    tags.push(...);
}
```

in which you can execute any code immediately that doesn't depend on the value of `id`.

Some time later, some event will cause the "commit" of this information.  You'll need to get an ID:

```
function generateID() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

and you'll need a function to process that ID and actually commit your data to the database, in this case making an AJAX call per tag:

```
function commitOneTag(id, tag) {
    return $.ajax(...);   
}

function commitTags(id) {
    return (function loop() {
        var tag = tags.shift();
        if (tag) {
            return commitOneTag(id, tag).then(loop);
        }
    })();
}
```

and then a way to chain it all together:

```
makeTag();
makeTag();

generateID().then(commitTags).done(function() {
    // processing will continue here once the entire
    // AJAX chain has been completed
 });
```

This is using `.then` to allow "chaining" of promises.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/5BHXt/ for a worked example

Comment: I appreciate you're answer , and it's a nice way to solve the problem. Anyway I need only a unique ID for all the tags.

Comment: I am thinking about one fact: I can push only a tag per request, do I have to make a request for every tag , according to the fact we are using an array?

Comment: @steo I updated the code (and fiddle) to demonstrate making a separate AJAX call for each tag request.

Answer (score 2):

Wow! I am looking at the promise() method for the very first time and I am already impressed. For your logic I think a psuedo code can be written like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myDeferredObj = $.Deferred();
var ajaxReq = function(){
    // Initial part of logic that does not need id
    alert('here');
    myDeferredObj.promise().done(function(args1, args2) {
        alert(args1 + ':' + args2);
        // Use id provided by generateID
    });
};

var generateID = function(){
    //get ID
    id = 5;//suppose
    alert('generate');
    myDeferredObj.resolveWith(this, [id, id]);
}

ajaxReq();
generateID();
});
```

This works fine for me! Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/569LL/

Comment: I don't think this use case can be handled using chaining, since chaining waits for the previous function to complete.

Comment: The OP mostly just needs to decouple his data handling and the AJAX requests.   His "insert" needs to go into a local data structure, and only once "id" is determined should the data structure be committed (via AJAX) to the database.  That's pretty much what my answer describes.

Comment: p.s. there's no need to call `.promise()` in your code.  The only purpose of that function is do return an object which has a _subset_ of the full `$.Deferred` functionality and hence can be _observed_ but not _modified_.

Comment: true that.. As I said touching this stuff for very first time :)

Comment: don't take this wrong way, but best get some more experience using them first.  You've kinda achieved what the OP wanted, except that the way he wanted it results in impenetrable code.  Note how in my code I've not had to touch the raw promise interface at all _and_ the flow of information is more logical.

Comment: Oh awesome! yeah, this is a way better technique. Took me a while to absorb that completely ;)
What I was doing was mainly debug @steo's code :-/